# How to import one modules from 'base' environment to 'tf' environment in anaconda?

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, environment, python-module

I have been working with `base` environment in `anaconda` till now and had installed all the required python modules/libraries. When I tried to install `tensorflow-cpu`, I came to know that I have to create another environment to install it from official documentation of `anaconda`. Now I have created the new environment named 'tf' to install `tensorflow-cpu`. Since I can activate only one environment at a time, I don't want want to install all the python modules/libraries again to this new `tf` environment as it will consume space in memory.

Is there any way, I can use all the modules of `base` environment to `tf` environment or vice versa?
Please help in this context!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely not a good idea too mix envs. They were invented to separate dependencies for independent projects. Trying to mix them is a "wrong" way of using envs.
Also, you don't have to create a new env when installing `tf` as the docs say, just install it where you want it to be, everything will work just fine. The docs recommend you to create one because it's not a good idea to install it into `base` env.

1. You have an env named `tf` now. Activate it and install all dependencies you need, then use it in your project.
2. Do not pollute your `base` env with packages, this one is not supposed to be used for development, rather for conda itself. Create a new env when you start a new project